# Siema carousel won't work I have added the file in my wp-includes

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, siema

I am trying to get [this](https://codepen.io/pawelgrzybek/pen/xRWEpR) work on my WP page but it won't work. I have downloaded the stable [release](https://github.com/pawelgrzybek/siema/releases) from here and added `siema.min.js` file in `wp-includes/js/slider/siema.min.js` and I first tried calling the file on the page by adding a script tab src and path. But it didn't work and than I added through Insert Header footer plugin. But it still doesn't work, rather is shows an image below the other.

HTML

```js
const mySiema = new Siema();
const prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
const next = document.querySelector('.next');

prev.addEventListener('click', () => mySiema.prev());
next.addEventListener('click', () => mySiema.next());
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 30rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.siema {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="siema">
  <div><img src="https://pawelgrzybek.com/siema/assets/siema--pink.svg" alt="Siema image" /></div>
  <div><img src="https://pawelgrzybek.com/siema/assets/siema--yellow.svg" alt="Siema image" /></div>
  <div><img src="https://pawelgrzybek.com/siema/assets/siema--pink.svg" alt="Siema image" /></div>
  <div><img src="https://pawelgrzybek.com/siema/assets/siema--yellow.svg" alt="Siema image" /></div>
</div>

<button class="prev">Prev</button>
<button class="next">Next</button>
```

[Webpage](https://my.nikah.io/slider/) in quesiton.

Comment: The Siema script seems to run, but before the page content is loaded. Add the script like this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51140/154474

Comment: Can you please advice, how? Is this error related to this? https://github.com/pawelgrzybek/siema/issues/65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to at least provide a selector to initialize `Siema`

```
const mySiema = new Siema({
  selector: '.siema',
});
```

[Here](https://pawelgrzybek.github.io/siema/#options) you'll find other options available.

**Note:** when you visit your website, there is an error in the browser console saying this. Also, don't forget to put your scripts inside a `$(document).ready(function(){});`

**Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const mySiema = new Siema({
    selector: '.siema'
  });
  const prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
  const next = document.querySelector('.next');

  prev.addEventListener('click', () => mySiema.prev());
  next.addEventListener('click', () => mySiema.next());
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 30rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.siema {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://my.nikah.io/wp-includes/js/slider/siema.min.js"></script>



<div class="siema">
  <div><img src="https://pawelgrzybek.com/siema/assets/siema--pink.svg" alt="Siema image" /></div>
  <div><img src="https://pawelgrzybek.com/siema/assets/siema--yellow.svg" alt="Siema image" /></div>
  <div><img src="https://pawelgrzybek.com/siema/assets/siema--pink.svg" alt="Siema image" /></div>
  <div><img src="https://pawelgrzybek.com/siema/assets/siema--yellow.svg" alt="Siema image" /></div>
</div>

<button class="prev">Prev</button>
<button class="next">Next</button>
```

**Update from comments**

Your page has a few errors and and a lot of warnings about [non unique id](https://www.google.com/search?ei=dx3PXN6mDYeA9QP2_rToDA&q=what+is+non+unique+id+in+html&oq=what+is+non+unique+id+in+html&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6524.9979..10211...0.0..1.199.1838.7j9......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i30j0i13j0i13i30j0i7i5i30j0i8i13i30j0i8i30j0i30j33i22i29i30j33i160.kSqC60S7LFA)

For now, it's hard to find the later errors, but the first one is causing your siema carousel not to work.

Your error says:

> `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

And your code is:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    const mySiema = new Siema({
      selector: '.siema'
    });
    const prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
    const next = document.querySelector('.next');
    </p> // remove this tag
    < p > // remove this tag
    prev.addEventListener('click', () => mySiema.prev());
    next.addEventListener('click', () => mySiema.next());
  });
</script>
```

That error means you have html tags in your script and a `<` is not expected at that position. Remove those `<p>` tags from the siema initialisation script. and it should work.

Comment: that pastebin code works perfectly fine. please don't say doesn't work, explain what is exactly happening. what do you see in the browser console ?

Comment: I am seeing a lot of error in the browser console. Don't know which is for this? This is my URL where I am trying https://my.nikah.io/slider/ and for error console this is the paste for it https://pastebin.com/rgjzNacf